# Can I replant a Bonsai into a bigger pot during growth?

Tags: bonsai, repotting

I've been gifted a Bonsai (jap. Hornbeam) which is already in growth (leaves have fully emerged). However the root bulb is already pretty dense and I'd like to put the bonsai into a bigger pot to increase trunk thickness and growth.

Can I repot the bonsai now if I don't prune the roots and try to disturb the root bulb as little as possible, or should I wait for the next early spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your bonsai looks like now (a photo would be very helpful), but for sure you can put your tree in a larger pot and it will grow taller. But please do keep in mind that bonsai is an art of keeping your tree small, and by training them and keeping them in small containers, the shape of the tree will looks like a miniature adult tree. A timely process. When you put it now in a larger container the trunk can thicken quicker, but the tree will lose this shape and it will take time to reshape it again later.